# Rails URL shorter that does *not* use an external service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Anyone could help me figure out a way to Short URL's from my own domain * without * using an external short service?

I have found several example apps on github for shortening urls but they all are dependent on an external service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try firefly

http://fireflyrb.com/